# How to actually clean up the repository on self-hosted runner after GitHub Actions completes?

Tags: github, github-actions

At the end of my workflow in GitHub actions, a "hidden" "post" job seems to run, and I can't seem to figure out how to *ignore* or *overwrite* it. For example, the `actions/checkout@v2` action seems to run the following when it's complete:

```
Post job cleanup.
/usr/bin/git version
git version 2.25.1
/usr/bin/git config --local --name-only --get-regexp core\.sshCommand
/usr/bin/git submodule foreach --recursive git config --local --name-only --get-regexp 'core\.sshCommand' && git config --local --unset-all 'core.sshCommand' || :
/usr/bin/git config --local --name-only --get-regexp http\.https\:\/\/github\.com\/\.extraheader
http.https://github.com/.extraheader
/usr/bin/git config --local --unset-all http.https://github.com/.extraheader
/usr/bin/git submodule foreach --recursive git config --local --name-only --get-regexp 'http\.https\:\/\/github\.com\/\.extraheader' && git config --local --unset-all 'http.https://github.com/.extraheader' || :
```

However, I just want to simply remove the entire repository from my self-hosted runner. Just a simple `rm -rf` in the directory.

I tried to just add this as a step in my `.yml` file, but that seems to break the `actions/checkout@v2` step that runs after my entire workflow is finished.

How can I clean up the repository entirely on the self-hosted running after the workflow is complete?

Comment: Looking at the source of checkout action, I don't see a way to override post job, but if you really need this, then you could fork the action and either remove the post job or make a parameter that would skip it.

Answer (score 16):

I was able to remove the entire repository before `actions/checkout@v2` using this:

```
   steps:

    - name: 'Cleanup build folder'
      run: |
        ls -la ./
        rm -rf ./* || true
        rm -rf ./.??* || true
        ls -la ./

    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
```

I've added the `ls -la ./` before and after, so I could double-check in the action log if everything was really gone.

The trick is to delete all `.??*` files as well, since `rm -rf ./*` won't remove files that start with dot, which meas the `.git` folder won't be deleted.

By running `rm -rf ./.??*` we remove all hidden files that have a dot as first character, including the `.git` folder, and then `actions/checkout@v2` will clone the repository properly, just like when running on github runners.

-H

Comment: worked as a breeze ! thanks

Comment: All solutions I find for cleaning the workspace are linux solutions. Equivalents for windows plebs I can't seem to find...

Answer (score 12):

> Looking at the source of checkout action, I don't see a way to override post job

Another approach is possible since Apr. 2022 (still in beta for now):

> ### [GitHub Actions: Job management hooks for self-hosted runners](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-04-04-github-actions-job-management-hooks-for-self-hosted-runners/)
>
> If you manage self-hosted runners for GitHub Actions, you can now specify shell scripts that run before the runner starts running a job from a workflow, and after a job completes.
>
> This allows you to perform a task on your self-hosted runner before a job starts and after a job ends, so you can set up your execution environment and clean up after workflow runs to ensure a consistent state on the runner itself, without requiring users to add that to their workflows.
>
> [Learn more about running scripts before or after a job](https://docs.github.com/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/running-scripts-before-or-after-a-job)

In your case, the "execution environment clean up" step can now be a pre-job script.

Answer (score 2):

as the selfhost on windows runs powershell `rm -Recurse ${{github.workspace}}\*` should work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).